# Can someone explain Thread Safety in layman terms?

Tags: java, thread-safety

Despite me reading wikipedia and such, I still don't really understand what Thread Safety means in a programming sense. Is anyone able to give some Java examples in layman terms? Such as what makes a thread safe vs a thread unsafe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is helpful to think in terms of concrete things outside the computer.  (Concurrent programming was being done long before the invention of digital computers.)

A car is a process.  An intersection is a shared resource.  If the light is green in multiple directions at the same time, then it is probably not thread safe.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! Makes a lot more sense now after rereading the wikipedia article a few times and then seeing your post made it click in my head. All the reentrant stuff was what was confusing me on what I thought I had an understanding of!

Answer (score 2):

It is a fuzzy term - there is no exact agreement on what it actually means.

Normally, however, people mean code that can be called from multiple threads concurrently without a chance of errors.

That is - code is considered thread safe if it can be called from multiple threads at the same time and is guaranteed not to cause errors.

Comment: So rereading Wikipedia, the part that I'm still not 100% sure about is that thread-safe means if I have some function, it is considered thread-safe if I can have multiple threads calling the same function without it causing errors. And errors can occur if they share some variable or some function that doesn't allow it to be run in multiple instances correct? And usually such an error will cause a hang, or crash?

So if I had some function that interrupts a running function, that function will only be declared thread-safe if I can safely resume it right?

Comment: @soulesschild - The main issue about thread safety is not just shared data (variable/s) - it is if the function is _changing_ the shared data in an unsafe manner.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the thread is safe or not.  It's how state in your objects are protected from being updated by multiple threads.  So, it's safe if only 1 thread can update a variable at a time so that you don't end up with some kind of inconsistent or unpredictable state.

An example of thread unsafe: You have an object that has an instance variable that stores a list of items that 1 method in that object uses to hold results of computations that it will return when it finishes.  If two threads call that method at the same time, both instances of that running method will try to update the same list so the methods' results will be intermingled.